# Site internet pour relire des textes

Tags: discussion, resources

Je prépare l'examen DELF B2 pendant l'été et j’ai besoin de corriger mes rédactions.

Je ne crois pas qu'ici soit le lieu parce que les questions sont spécifiques. Est-ce que vous connaissez quelque site internet ou réseau social qui peut m'aider? Ou vous considérez que je peux demander ici ?

Comment: J'utilise fréquemment [BonPatron](http://bonpatron.com) quand je n'ai pas accès à antidote.

Comment: Effectivement nous ne corrigeons pas les textes et exercices, mais si tu as une question spécifique sur la langue française (point de grammaire, vocabulaire, etc.) nous y répondrons avec plaisir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lang-8](http://lang-8.com/)

(signalé sur ELL)

C'est sur inscription mais gratuit pour une utilisation de base. On soumet un texte dans une langue qu'on étudie, il est corrigé par des utilisateurs de langue maternelle. En contrepartie on est sollicité pour corriger des textes dans notre langue maternelle.